# How to handle mouseover and mouseout events for ul li in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Tried to show and hidden the span tag using mouseover and mouseout. But not working.
ul, li is generating dynamically, So, I am trying to add display block and none.But it is not working.How to do it? If anyone knows, Please help to resove this issue.

app.component.html:

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">

<li class="item"> 
  <a>Test1</a>
  <span> -On </span> 
</li>
<li class="item"> 
  <a>Test2</a>
  <span> -On </span> 
</li>
<li class="item"> 
  <a>Test3</a>
  <span> -On </span> 
</li>

</ul>
```

app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
let m = this.elRef.nativeElement
  .querySelector('#list > ul')
  .querySelectorAll('li');

m.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log('Event triggered');
    el.nextElementSibling('span').style.display = 'block';
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    console.log('Event out');
    el.nextElementSibling('span').style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

}

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qw6hvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ho27c

```
.item > span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.item:hover > span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Can we do using typescript?

Comment: Yes, there a many solutions. Here is a example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-abxhtt

Comment: The downside with this solutions is, that every time when you hover over a item, the component renders again, with CSS that is not happening.